# Adding PostBackTrigger and AsyncPostBackTriggers to UpdatePanel for dynamically generated checkboxes with checkedChanged EventHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net

For more clear explanation here's my code on `.asp` file:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlTabs" runat="server" >
   <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" />
   </Triggers>
  <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:Panel ID="pnlCheckList" runat="server" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" CssClass="listingDummyTab">
   </asp:Panel>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

On my `.cs` code, I dynamically created checkeboxes to the pnlCheckList like this:

```
CheckBox chkModuleID = new CheckBox();
chkModuleID.ID = drNew[def.ID].ToString();
chkModuleID.AutoPostBack = true;
chkModuleID.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkID_OnRow_Check);
pnlCheckList.Controls.Add(chkModuleID);
```

Now my problem here is when I change the check boxes the whole page have to load instead of the content of the `UpdatePanel`. Note that the EventHandler for the dynamically created checkboxes is firing but not inside the UpdatePanel.

How can I add the `ID`'s of the dynamically created `Controls` in `<Triggers>` of the `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: Have you tried [`ScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerasyncpostbackcontrol.aspx) method?

Comment: I already tried to declare `AsyncPostBackTrigger` object then I assigned a `ControlID` to it, but when I add it to the `UpdatePanel` there is a problem upon reload or postback. The object I created are added again.

Comment: Have you read The Answer [Here]:(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715623/how-can-i-programmatically-add-triggers-to-an-asp-net-updatepanel)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way of adding dynamic (or programmatically created) controls to the markup, therefore, you must register the control with the `ScriptManager` after creating it.

Per the `AsyncPostBackTrigger` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb493884.aspx), adding an `AsyncPostBackTrigger` control programmatically is not supported:

> To programmatically register a postback control, use the `RegisterAsyncPostBackControl` method of the `ScriptManager` control. Then call the Update method of the `UpdatePanel` control when the control posts back.

---

Basically what you should be doing is registering the CheckBox control after creating it.

```
// original code
CheckBox chkModuleID = new CheckBox();
chkModuleID.ID = drNew[def.ID].ToString();
chkModuleID.AutoPostBack = true;
chkModuleID.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkID_OnRow_Check);
pnlCheckList.Controls.Add(chkModuleID);

// register the control to cause asynchronous postbacks
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(chkModuleID);
```

**Important:** Inside of your `chkID_OnRow_Check` callback/eventhandler function, ensure you call `UpdatePanel1.Update()`.

**Update 2013-02-20**

Due to the my understanding of the exception you are receiving, consider making the CheckBox IDs unique.

```
// One possibility is this - assuming you don't require a consistent ID
chkModuleID.ID = String.Format("{0}-{1}", drNew[def.ID].ToString(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
```

Comment: I don't understand,but it still keeps on adding the same trigger.

Comment: @BlackHatShadow do you mean that the trigger is added every time, or are you seen some other side effect? Can you please elaborate some more?

Comment: When I try to fill the panel (includes the triggers), the triggers are adding again pawning a runtime error for multiple `ID's`

Comment: How do I check if there is an existing trigger in my UpdatePanel? Thank you for your attention and effort by the way.

Comment: Can you update the question with the exception you are receiving, please? Also, ensure you are having unique ID's for the chkModuleID, see the 2013-02-20 update.